# Call google+ API with token

Tags: python, google-app-engine, google-api, google-plus, google-oauth

How can i call Google+ API using access token in python, currently i am using the flow method which first exchanges the authentication url then it exchange credentials.

My code is this:

```
FLOW = OAuth2WebServerFlow(
        client_id=client id,
        client_secret=secret,
        scope=scope,
        user_agent=user_agent,redirect_uri=redirect_uri)

auth_uri = FLOW.step1_get_authorize_url()



credentials=FLOW.step2_exchange(code)


people_service = apiclient.discovery.build('people', 'v1',credentials=credentials)
connections = people_service.people().connections().list(resourceName='people/me').execute()
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to actually visit the `auth_uri` web page, the user would log in and get an authentication code and it would redirect back to your application.
In a non-browser application you would do this out-of-band (OOB) and with `redirect_uri='urn:ietf:wg:oauth:2.0:oob'` and you could `print(auth_uri)`, cut & paste it into a browser address bar and enter your user credentials.

When you get the authentication code you need to assign it to `code` in your script above, e.g. (for OOB):

```
code = input("Code: ")   # raw_input() in Py2
```

Then the rest of your code would work fine.

I would consider looking at the `oauthclient.<type>.Storage` modules to store the credentials received from `FLOW.step2_exchange()`. So you don't necessarily need to do this exchange each time.

Comment: Yes i know that this code is working fine. What i need to do is to call the google apis with access token because my android app is generating the access token and i want to use that access token.